# Favorite Questions and Answers from second quarter 2018

Tags: discussion, blog

### Update

The [post](https://thesffblog.com/2018/07/highlights-from-2018-2nd-quarter/) is now available on the blog site.

### Original

Please link to your favorite questions and answers which were either asked or answered from April 1st 2018 through June 30 2018 (**They don't have to be *your* questions and answers, but it also doesn't matter if you want to self promote your own stuff.**).

Your answers will be compiled into a blog post like previous [quarterly posts](https://thesffblog.com/category/qotw/).

I will be using DavRob60's queries for a baseline, but I really appreciate people voicing the ones they really enjoyed. Maybe you feel like you answered one really well, even if it didn't receive a lot of votes. Let me know about it.

- [Questions with most **Votes** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106579/questions-with-most-votes-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2018/04/01)
- [Questions with most **View** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106705/questions-with-most-view-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2018/04/01)
- [Questions with **best answer** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106709/questions-with-best-answer-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2018/04/01)

**I will also be linking all blog posts that happened within this quarter. Also the most controversial question of the quarter. Also a sum of all the bounties that were awarded.**

Also if there was a meta post you feel should be spotlighted those are also acceptable.

[image: Han Solo prequel film will mostly be about how he skipped class the day they taught units of measurements. Kessel in 12 milliliters]

Answer (score 2):

#### Questions:

1. [Did Varys set Tyrion up?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/186172/54887) by [Paul.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/66948/paul)
2. [Which Wonders and Wonders Made by Man has Tyrion visited?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/189126/54887) by [TheLethalCarrot.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/58193/thelethalcarrot)
3. [Was it really pork?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/186812/54887) by [Paul.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/66948/paul)

#### Answers:

1. [TheLethalCarrot's](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/58193/thelethalcarrot) answer to [Is Cotter Pyke the only illiterate in high ranks?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/185432/54887)
2. [JAD's](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/86196/jad) answer to [Which wonders and wonders made by man has Tyrion visited?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/189130/54887)
3. [TheLethalCarrot's](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/58193/thelethalcarrot) answer to [Did Varys set Tyrion up?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/186175/54887)

Comment: This is a very good list of posts... or at least half of them are ;P

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Not like there was much choice haha, you're on everything asoiaf from the 2nd quarter.

Comment: This is clearly favouritism for @TheLethalCarrot. These are favourite Q&As not favourite user who posted Questions and Answers! The voting is a lie!

Comment: @Edlothiad: ^_^ Well, they have been very active...

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I know, I know. And Egg knows I’m kidding.